# Algebraic Structures Books

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I wanted to ask you guys if you know any books where I can learn basic stuff about Algebraic Structures and Groups.

Thank you.

Comment: I am very uncertain what sort of book you are looking for, especially given that you tagged this with combinatorics, rather than abstract-algebra.

Comment: Try searching the website for book recommendations for learning abstract algebra.